# bitmapdata.draw failing silently

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to read an image using Loader (variable name is faceimage) and trying to pass the bitmapdata of that image to a function called detect. However, it is failing in the line where I am trying to get the Bitmap.

```
    bmpTarget = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( faceImage.width, faceImage.height, false ) )
    bmpTarget.bitmapData.draw( faceImage ); // Fails, no errors shown
    detector.detect( bmpTarget.bitmapData );
```

I narrowed down to this line by putting trace statements above and below the failing line. The faceImage contains valid data which I verified by displaying contents on screen. I also tried

```
    bmpTarget = Bitmap(BitmapData(faceImage.content))
```

but in vain. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a sandbox/crossdomain issue. Certain crossdomain settings prohibit drawing the content of a loaded image to a bitmapData. You can get around it by loading the raw image data with `URLLoader` and then using `loadBytes` on `Loader`.

Comment: I am actually loading the image from my local filesystem at the moment. Will crossdomain issues still crop up? I tried this piece of code, but it still seems to be failing.

Answer (score 1):

As noted from:
[Why do Loader objects kill bitmapdata draw();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883850/why-do-loader-objects-kill-bitmapdata-draw)

You likely need a `LoaderContext`.

```
loader.load("http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg", new LoaderContext(true));
```

Otherwise, you can load images from other sites but not access the actual bitmapData, which a `draw()` requires.

Comment: I am actually loading the image from my local filesystem at the moment. I tried this piece of code, but it still doesn't seem to be working :-(

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're trying to access the bitmapdata before it's been loaded?

Perhaps try using a complete listener...

```
var _urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("urlToImage");
var faceImage:Loader = new Loader;
faceImage.load(_urlRequest);
faceImage.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void{ trace(e) });
faceImage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded, false, 0, true);

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {

faceImage.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
var bmpTarget:Bitmap = e.target.content;
detector.detect( bmpTarget.bitmapData );
}
```